# Implementing one language per field with Searchkick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, searchkick

I'm trying to add multi-language support of a Rails app which uses searchkick for search functionality.

After some research I've decided to go with the one language per field approach as described [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/one-lang-fields.html). However, after googling for quite a bit, I couldn't find any documentation on this topic in terms of get it implemented with searchkick.

Essentially, I cannot find the way to specify a language analyzer for a given field using searchkick.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [custom mapping](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick#advanced-mapping) with [language analyzers](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-lang-analyzer.html)

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  searchkick mappings: {
    properties: {
      title_en: {type: "text", analyzer: "english"},
      title_fr: {type: "text", analyzer: "french"},
    }
  }
end
```

and probably a [custom search query](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick#advanced-search)

```
products = Product.search body: {query: {match: {title_en: "milk"}}}
```

Comment: Thanks. Exactly the solution I ended up with while waiting for the answer.